# Does django-celery-backend only save a record when the task completes?

Tags: django-celery, celery-task

I've been doing some testing on [django-celery-results](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results).

I have found that the task result is only stored when the task completes, using the sqlite db.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with `django-celery-results` but a quick glance at it's code suggests it's just saving data using django ORM, which implies that same rules for regular celery should apply.

In such case, yes, by default, only success is stored (you can read more about it [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#built-in-states), but generally only terminal states are stored by default).

You can tweak this by settings the flag to track *started* state [more info here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.track_started)

```py
track_started = False
```

Note that `Pending` state is not really persisted, but is returned when no other state for that task exists [more info here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.track_started).

Comment: _which implies that same rules for regular celery should apply_...I checked the `AsyncResult` and it had a pending state while the `TaskResult` did not exist until it became a success.

Comment: Also _Tasks are either pending, finished, or waiting to be retried_...yet in my case there is never a pending `TaskResult` db record, when I run locally.

Comment: With `track_started` the db record is saved immediately but with the status of `STARTED` and not `PENDING`

Comment: Pending state is a virtual state, it is what you get when there is no row in the tasks table for that Task id. It is some what misleading.

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b54da11598fc6a7e360ca9bc09e1bcdfafa3cd1f/celery/backends/base.py#L732

Comment: For django-celery-results users the celery setting for settings.py is "CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True" to enable this.